# Continuous function in two variables

Tags: integration, continuity

Let's have a look to the function $F(a,b)=\int_0^{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt}$, then this function describes the length of the arc of an ellipse ($a,b>0$). Can we see when this function $F$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$? I would say: if we can estimate the integral we are done. Is this right?

Thanks

Comment: $F$ is continuous on all of $(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)$, since the integrand is continuous as a function $(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)\times[0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$, and the interval of integration is closed and bounded.

Answer (score 2):

The function $F$ is continuous at all points of the domain $(0, \infty) \times (0, \infty)$. Indeed, it's differentiable at all those points, and hence automatically continuous. (The derivatives are determined by "differentiating through the integral"). I'm not sure what you last sentence means, so I won't try to address it.